# How can I use recursion and memoization to understand whether the a string is a combination of other two strings?

Tags: recursion, memoization

Consider 2 strings:

```
a = "wxy"
b = "mnop"
z = "wmxnoyp"
```

string z is a mixedstring if it is a combination of string a and b such that the length of string z is equal to the sum of the length of string a and b and not a single alphabet from either string a and b are repeated. Also note that every character is in increasing order of string a and b. For instance, if

```
a = "tuim"
b = "oprn"
z = "moiprunt"
```

z is not a mixedstring as even though length of z is equal to the sum of length of string a and b, string z is not in an increasing order of string a and b.

I want my code to return true if z is a mixedstring of a and b, and return false if string z is not a mixedstring of a and b.

How do I write my code using recursion and memoization? I understand that I will require my code to use a two dimensional array to store values that have already been calculated (as a table), however, I do not understand what the x and y axis of my table should represent and how my code should fill values in that table.

If someone can give a brief explanation of what the table should look like with an example, that would be great.

Comment: There is no reason to use memoization here, since the problem is solved with a greedy algorithm.

Comment: please clarify "not a single alphabet from either string a and b are repeated". can `b` contain any characters from `a` (or `a` from `b`)? for example, do any "mixedstring"s exist for `a="abc"` and `b="cde"` ?

Answer (score 0):

This problem does not need dynamic programming. It can be solved with a greedy algorithm. We can iterate the `z` string and see if the corresponding character matches either the first character from `a` or from `b`. If not, then there is no success. If there is a match, then repeat with the next character from `z`, but now discarding the already matched character from either `a` or `b`, ...etc.

Here is how it could look (Python):

```py
def is_combination(a, b, z):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    for ch in z:
        if i < len(a) and ch == a[i]:
            i += 1
        elif j < len(b) and ch == b[j]:
            j += 1
        else:
            return False
    return i == len(a) and j == len(b)
```